# iFrame & Galleria Photo Gallery [makeshift multi album] -- resize? fullscreen? jquery? java?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, galleria

So what I have now (http://itsdoom.com/tumblrstylewebsite.html)

is the newest thing I have been working on.  its very rough as of now.  But what I am having trouble with is the image gallery.  If you click on 'work' it will scroll you down and you can see what I'm talking about.  I wanted to have multiple albums so I placed the "Galleria" in an iFrame.  with obvious problems.  As I realize the way i have it setup now the Galleria / iframe is at 420px (h) x 820px (w), which looks good on the screen i'm working on now 1280x800, but if a user had a higher screen resolution, it would look too small, and with no ability to fullscreen the galleria, its a problem.

so I have a couple questions..

1. Is there anyway to make the Galleria fullscreen not only in the iframe but in the whole browser?
2. Is there anyway to either resize the iframe // content (Galleria) to reflect a users screen resolution?

If there's a way to fullscreen that would be the best option because someone with a higher resolution screen would just be able to hit that.  if not, hopefully the other option is possible.

Comment: Why would you want to put it in an `<iframe>`?

Comment: is there another way to do multiple albums w/ galleria?
i thought it was my only option

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can (might work):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('iframe[name="gallery"]').find('.galleria-fullscreen').bind('click', function() {
    $('iframe[name="gallery"]').css('position', 'absolute');
    $('iframe[name="gallery"]').width($(window).width());
    $('iframe[name="gallery"]').height($(window).height());
  });
});
```

Comment: would that go in the main html?

Comment: or the galleria js..or the galleria html

Comment: sorry im not gonna lie, im new to this

Comment: To the main HTML file. You *can* try both, though ;)

Comment: added it to all the html and js files and nothing changed
thanks anyway blender